# Почему программа завершается с ошибкой синтаксиса при передачи обычной анонимной функции в then?

Tags: javascript

```js
let promise = Promise.resolve(42);

promise.then(fucntion(value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

Не работает, когда использование стрелочного синтаксиса срабатывает:

```js
let promise = Promise.resolve(42);

promise.then((value) => console.log(value));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Потому что у вас вместо `function` написано `fuCNtion`

```js
let promise = Promise.resolve(42);

promise.then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
});
```